# Ajax not executing vb.net function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery

I found a project in C# that i am trying to convert to vb.net i almost got it done but i just can not get the last function to work

Javascript and Ajax code

```
       $('#sendBtn').live('click', function () {
        var image = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas").toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = image;
        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Default.aspx/UploadImage',
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Image sent!');
            }
        });
    });
```

VB.NET code

```
Namespace CanvasToServer
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Sub UploadImage(imageData As String)
        'FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\image.png", FileMode.Create);
        'FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\image.jpg", FileMode.Create);
        Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\image.png", FileMode.Create)
        Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fs)
        Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData)
        bw.Write(data)
        bw.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

ASPX Code

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="CanvasToServer._Default" %>
```

Link to Tut: http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/send-canvas-content-to-server/

The only thing thats not working is the save to server functie but i am not getting any errors pleas advice

Comment: What happens ? any errors ? any debugging done in the JavaScript ? is the POST request being sent to the server ?

Comment: are you sure the UploadImage method is being fired?

Comment: No the uploadimage function is not firing thats the problem and i dont get any errors in javascript if i look in F12 function from IE i cant check in FF with FireBug becase the canvas is not being showed there I. I did put an alert before the $.ajax({ and that whas being executed.    when i check on the netwerk tab from IE debugger is get message URL /default.aspx/uploadimage    methode POST     result is 404

Comment: Oke Its working i just tryd putting my project name before the default.aspx/uploadimage tested that whasent working changed back to old way i posted here is working ??? this is CRAZY Wait the error whas becase tof the / before the link

Comment: I wouldn't use `.live` as it's deprecated.  See http://api.jquery.com/live/